# Error "Cannot set property 'eventManager' of null" in Dynamics 365

Tags: javascript, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365

I got this script error popup when I opened record today. I have never got this error before and there's no change after I last opened the record days ago.

The error message is `"TypeError: Unable to set property 'eventManager' of undefined or null reference".`

I have no idea about it and need help to solve this issue. It occurred in both sandbox and prod environment.

Comment: Do you have any custom JavaScript on the form?

Answer (score 1):

I also have this problem. It seems that last crm system update contains some changes regarding js. In my case this error is made by the js function where I add OnLoad event to subgrid. If that function is disabled everything works fine.

Comment: I have some onload event to the form. However, this alert pop up sometimes but not each time I opened a record. Do you have this same issue?

Comment: Yes. It also show error popup at my end only sometimes when I open the record. But even if error popup is not shown then add button in one subgid for 1:N relation is missing. I am trying to add OnLoad event to this subgrid. But if I disable function where I add OnLoadEvent to the grid then everything works fine. Can you check in anywhere on onload form event you are trying to add onload event to subgrid? [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn932126.aspx#BKMK_subgridAddOnLoad). Using this function is making this error at my end. And it was working fine few days ago.

Answer (score 0):

its a known bug since the last update.

https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/239844

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft is removing their support for customised Javascript on forms. Please check if your Legacy form rendering is switched on . If yes , then switch it off and convert all your custom JS code to Xrmtoolkit compatible code.

Regarding your issue, there is a work around where you can wrap the addOnLoad call inside a window.setTimeout call with a delay of 1000ms.

`window.setTimeout(onload(){//your code}, 1000);`